# lua transition.to onComplete function isnt working

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local link = require("link")
local walkingData = require("Animation")

local walk_right
local walk_down
local walk_left
local walk_up

--loading in the sprite sheet and animation data
local options = link.getSpriteSheetData()
local walking = walkingData.getAnimationSequences()

-- creating the image sheet and sprite
local sheet1 = graphics.newImageSheet("link.png", options)

local linkWalk = display.newSprite(sheet1, walking)

linkWalk.x = 40
linkWalk.y= display.contentHeight - 60

--start the loop by transition
--linkWalk:setSequence("Walking up")
--linkWalk:play()
--transition.to(linkWalk, {y= 60, time= 8000, onComplete = walk_right})

local function walk_right ()

    linkWalk:setSequence("Walking right")
    linkWalk:play()
    transition.to(linkWalk, {x=display.contentWidth - 60, time= 3200, 
onComplete=walk_down})

end

local function walk_left ()

    linkWalk:setSequence("Walking left")
    linkWalk:play()
    transition.to(linkWalk, {x= 60, time= 3200, onComplete = walk_up})
end

local function walk_up ()

    linkWalk:setSequence("Walking up")
    linkWalk:play()
    transition.to(linkWalk, {y= 60, time= 8000, onComplete = walk_right})

end

local function walk_down ()

    linkWalk:setSequence("Walking down")
    linkWalk:play()
    transition.to(linkWalk, {y=display.contentHeight - 60, time= 8000, 
onComplete = walk_left})

end

--starting by making the sprite move upward
walk_up()'
```

i am in a class for corona and am having trouble with an assignment i am trying to get a sprite image to walk around the boarder of the device but the sprite moves up and goes right then stops. why would it be that the transition.to onComplete function works properly in the first function called but not by the one called by the onComplete function. i have tried multiple ways of starting it but have only gotten as far as to move right, is there a better way to go from transition to transition?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - If you have "tried multiple ways" then you should include what you've tried in your question so we can help you build on that

Comment: it included not calling a function to "jumpstart" it for lack of a better term and used a transition function with the onComplete function calling the function, that one didnt even get as far as the code i have listed i have updated it with the code from before

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
local composer   = require 'composer' 

local scene = composer.newScene()
local sprite


function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    local _T = display.screenOriginY
    local _B = display.viewableContentHeight - display.screenOriginY
    local _L = display.screenOriginX
    local _R = display.viewableContentWidth - display.screenOriginX

    sprite = display.newImage( sceneGroup, 'bubble.png', 0, 0 )
    sprite.index = 1

    local data = { 
        { x=sprite.width * 0.5,      y=_B - sprite.height * 0.5, time=3200 },
        { x=sprite.width * 0.5,      y=_T + sprite.height * 0.5, time=8000 },
        { x=_R - sprite.width * 0.5, y=_T + sprite.height * 0.5, time=3200 },
        { x=_R - sprite.width * 0.5, y=_B - sprite.height * 0.5, time=8000 },
        { x=sprite.width * 0.5,      y=_B - sprite.height * 0.5, time=3200 }
    }

    function sprite.onComplete( self )

        if self.index < 5 then 

            local prevTrans = data[self.index]
            local nextTrans = data[self.index + 1]
            nextTrans.onComplete = self.onComplete
            self.index = self.index + 1
            self.x, self.y = prevTrans.x, prevTrans.y
            transition.to( self, nextTrans )

        end

    end 



end

function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase     = event.phase

    if phase == 'will' then

    elseif phase == 'did' then

        sprite.onComplete( sprite )

    end
end

function scene:hide( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase     = event.phase

    if phase == 'will' then

    elseif phase == 'did' then

    end
end

function scene:destroy( event )

end

scene:addEventListener( 'create', scene )
scene:addEventListener( 'show', scene )
scene:addEventListener( 'hide', scene )
scene:addEventListener( 'destroy', scene )

return scene
```

I use custom image and composer module.